# NameError: name 'open' is not defined When trying to log to files

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, discord.py

So I chose to implement logging in my discord.py bot which is fine and dandy and works alright. but once I add logging to files, be it through using a filehandler

```
handler = logging.FileHandler(
    filename="../logs/bot.log",
    mode="a")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(name)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
```

Or through the basicConfig

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="../logs/bot.log", filemode="a", format="%(asctime)s %(name)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I always get this Traceback on exit

```
Exception ignored in: <function ClientSession.__del__ at 0x7fe1330b9790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/coconutbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 314, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1740, in call_exception_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1463, in error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1577, in _log
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1587, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1649, in callHandlers
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 950, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1182, in emit
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function ClientResponse.__del__ at 0x7fe13300b430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/coconutbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 757, in __del__
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/coconutbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 177, in release
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/coconutbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 629, in _release
  File "/home/lukas/PycharmProjects/coconutbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 62, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 690, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I'm utterly stumped as to what  did wrong as the Traceback doesnt include any of my own files. I'm suspecting I might have to do some manual cleanup but even if I do `logging.shutdown()` I get the same Traceback

Answer (score 22):

That is because something (`asyncio` in this case) tries to log during the shutting down phase of the interpreter.

This is a known problem. A [workaround](https://bugs.python.org/issue26789) for the `logging` module has been implemented in python 3.10

It happens because the name `open` has already been deleted by the garbage collector before the file handler got the time to use it.

You can avoid this problem by trying to explicitly close/release your resources before your program exit.

Comment: Well I tried doing that by calling logging.shutdown() in atexit but it didnt work.
Other than that nothing I can do?

Comment: @Voreck `logging.shutdown()` has already been registered for `atexit` ever since. You don’t need to call it by yourself. Instead, try to close the event loop, the connection, etc that your program has.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, using both Python 3.9 and 3.10 (despite the discussion noted in @dragon2fly's answer). I wasn't using asyncio directly, but I was using a [Rich logging handler](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) which I suspect is using asynio in the background. Calls to `logging.shutdown()` did not fix the issue as suggested in https://bugs.python.org/issue42203.

The only thing that worked is right before my script terminates is to call

```
logger.handlers.clear()
```

which effectively unregisters the Rich handler for my logger object `logger`.