# How to prevent premature deletion of built-in functions by garbage collector on application exit

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Here is a short script with a class that dumps some data to disk upon destruction:

```
import pickle

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._some_data = "lorem ipsum dolor sit"

    def __del__(self):
        with open("/some/file/to/dump/data.pickle", 'wb') as ofile:
            pickle.dump(self._some_data, ofile)

my_instance = MyClass()
# script ends, causing garbage collector to clean up and delete my_instance, which triggers __del__()
```

The issue is that `__del__()` uses the built-in `open()` function, which may be deleted by the garbage collector on application exit before `my_instance` is deleted. This then causes an *"NameError: name 'open' is not defined"* error. This reason for this problem is described in more detail here (but without solution): [NameError: name 'open' is not defined When trying to log to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679139/nameerror-name-open-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-log-to-files)

However, when playing around I found a workaround by overwriting the open function with itself by adding the silly looking line `open = open`:

```
import pickle
open = open


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._some_data = "lorem ipsum dolor sit"

    def __del__(self):
        with open("/some/file/to/dump/data.pickle", 'wb') as ofile:
            pickle.dump(self._some_data, ofile)


my_instance = MyClass()
```

This will now work and dump `self._some_data` to disk.

I have multiple questions:

1. Why precisely does this actually work? My first instinct was that `MyClass` is depending on the local `open()`, so the garbage collector will delete `open()` after `my_instance`. However, in that case i do not understand why the first version does not work because similarly, it is depending on the built-in `open()`, which should also prevent its premature deletion.
2. Is this workaround actually reliable? I might just have been lucky and that in another version of python this will/would not work.
3. Is there a better way to solve this problem? While there is some elegance in the simplicity of this workaround, this also looks very hacky.

Comment: I think this is a misuse of `__del__()`. See the docs. There's no guarantee`__del__()` is called when the interpreter exits, so your dump may never occur. I'd guess the hack works because it creates a circular reference that requires the cyclic collector, which runs only once in a while. I'm not a Python expert, so take these comments as hints at where to look next. The better pattern is to code the dump explicitly. Relying on an opaque mechanism like garbage collection to invoke a side effect is not good practice.

Comment: Whether something is a misuse or not depends on the context. I am using it to dump some cached data to disk on application exit, but its not important at all that it happens. If not, the next start up will just be a bit longer. 
My main concern was whether or not the syntax is reliable, as in whether or not __del__() will reliably not throw an error, and not whether or not __del__() gets executed reliably. But i see that i could have worded this clearer.

Comment: @Leander Moesinger a possible idea for 3. use a context manager implementing custom `__enter__` & `__exit__` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that `MyClass` (or it's instances) somehow "depends" on `open` is not entirely correct. What actually happens in `__del__` (or any other method or function) is that at the point where `open` is called, the interpreter will look-up the *name* "open" in the global namespace, and use whatever object it finds there. As such, the "dependency" on `open` is only resolved *at the time the `open` method is called, and only for the local context*. This usually works out fine, unless finalization has already begun, and what one can ordinarily expect to be in `globals()` is no longer there.

With respect to you question:

1. The line `open = open` does not "overwrite" the function with itself. The line creates a new binding inside the module's namespace, called "open" (the first "open" in `open = ...`); the value assigned to that binding is what the interpreter will get when looking up the name "open" (the second "open" in `... = open`) in the global namespace. That value is - no surprises - the built-in `open`-function, which is now bound to both the local module's namespace under the name "open" and the global namespace under the (same) name "open".
   When your `__del__`-method calls `open`, the interpreter searches the local module's namespace for the name "open", falling back to the global namespace as described above. That extra binding in the module's namespace is what keeps the `open` function from being destroyed, as it is not only bound in the global, but also in the local module's namespace. As such, there are two paths to reach the function's implementation, and even if the set of `built-in` bindings is being destroyed, the local module's namespace has a path to it that is still reachable.
2. Relying on `__del__` being executed at all is never a good idea. There are many reasons for that. In general, the destructor should only care about destroying the object and releasing resources that would otherwise be wasted / blocked *if the program continues*. Yet you should always assume that the destructor does not execute at all (think `abort()`).
3. The [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module provides a more reliable way to achieve what you want.